# Is there something like KVO in Kitura?

Tags: swift, kitura

Is there anything like KVO in Kitura? I know that this is something from Objective-C that we can use in iOS, but is there anything like that for observation? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not. Swift 4 added keypaths which are similar to KVC, but Swift/Kitura doesn't have anything like KVO.